# Solr System Space Usage

Tags: solr

We upgraded solr from 5 to solr 6. Im seeing an increase in swap space in solr dashboard.

Can you explain what the difference is between dark grey, light grey and white in space in solr dashboard and what it means?
I have attached two screenshots of old solr and new sorl respectively.
SOLR 5
[image]

NEW SOLR 6
[image]

Answer (score 0):

white space = heap memory

light gray = total space allocated to solr service

dark gray = out of total allocated space, actually how much space your service is using